# DataGridView.Columns.AddRange c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am a Vb.Net Programmer, new to C#

In Vb.Net I use AddRange to Add Multiple column in DataGridView

```
dim Col1 As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
dim Col2 As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    MyDataGridView1.Columns.AddRange({Col1, Col2})
```

This is accepted in VB.Net

in c# I have wrote

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Col1 = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Col2 = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(); 

     MyDataGridView1.Columns.AddRange({Col1, Col2});
```

This is not accepted in C#. 
Where I Wrong???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Col1 = new  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
Col1.HeaderText = "test";
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Col2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
Col2.HeaderText = "test2";

MyDataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new[] {Col1,Col2});
```

Note that the "new" is all lower-case as well.

Answer (score 4):

From [`DataGridViewColumnCollection.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.addrange.aspx)

> Parameters
>
> Type: System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[]
>
> An array of DataGridViewColumn objects to add.

So, I think you should use;

```
MyDataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new[] { Col1, Col2 });
```

Since you are new in C#, I should explain what is `new[]` mean?

*Microsoft* introduced the concept called *[implicitly typed arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx)* to the language with *C# 3.0*. With this concept,  you don't have to explicitly define the data type of the variables, you can specify that the compiler should examine the elements of the array to determine the type that should be applied.

The initial declaration of a data type is replaced by the *[`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/bb383973.aspx)* keyword.

```
var numbers = new[] {"one", "two", "three"};
```

When you build, the compiler scans the contents of the array and determines that every item is a `string`. Therefore, creates a **string array**.

Comment: He is new to C#. You should mention that you are creating an implicitly typed array, otherwise the OP may be confused about the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The "New" keyword would need to be lowercase.

Other than that, prefix `{ Col1, Col2 }` like so:

```
MyDataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new[] { Col1, Col2 });
```

Additionally, Resharper gives a warning if the array is typed to `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, so you might want to explicitly match the array type to the parameter type as follows:

```
MyDataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] { Col1, Col2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
MyDataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] { Col1, Col2 });
```

Hope This helps.